Angular 14 Micro Frontend route is not working
I am new in the creating micro front end application. I'm trying to create a proof-of-concept on it. Code is successfully compiled, but routing is not working when loading module dynamically.
When I am running route localhost:4200/product-listing, it is not working and it is redirecting me to localhost:4200.
I am trying to achieve micro front end application in Angular using module federation.
Code for shell app:
app.routing.module.ts:
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { loadRemoteModule } from '@angular-architects/module-federation';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', //this is an example internal route to component that exists inside shell app
    redirectTo :'home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path :'home',
    component:AppComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'product-listing',
    loadChildren: () => loadRemoteModule({
      type:'module',
      remoteEntry: 'http://localhost:3100/remoteEntry.js',
      exposedModule: './ProductListingModule'
    }).then( m => {return m.ProductListingModule}).catch(error =>
      console.log('Error=>', error))
  },
  {
    path: 'shopping-cart',
    loadChildren: () => loadRemoteModule({ 
      remoteEntry: 'http://localhost:3200/remoteEntry.js',
      remoteName: 'shoppingCart', 
      exposedModule: './ShoppingCartModule' }).then(m => m.ShoppingCartModule)
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }

Code for product listing module:
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require('webpack').container.ModuleFederationPlugin;

module.exports = {
  output: {
    uniqueName: 'productListing',
    publicPath: 'auto',
  },
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: 'productListing',
      filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
      exposes: {
        './ProductListingModule': './src/app/product-listing/product-listing.module.ts',
      },
      shared: ['@angular/core', '@angular/common', '@angular/router'],
    }),
  ],
};

app.routing.module.ts   //for product listing
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
const routes: Routes = [{ 
  path: '', 
  component: AppComponent, 
  pathMatch: 'full'
}];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }

I have added code for shell app i.e the parent one in a way and added one module i.e. the product listing.
Code has been added with routing and webpack.config.json.
My expectations is it supposed to work on route localhost:4200/product-listing.
Thanks in advance
